# Image don't appear on button ControlTemplate WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I'm having a problem with ControlTemplates.

When I try to put a image in the button, the image don't appear on the application. Here the style:

```
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Grid Margin="3 2">
                        <Rectangle Name="r1" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="2 2"/>
                        <Border Name="border" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"  CornerRadius="130" BorderThickness="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ShadowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="roundedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />

        <Setter Property="Background" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0.6" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEEEE" Offset="0.2"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.85"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCCCCCC" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4,2" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC" CornerRadius="130,130,130,130" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid >
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow" Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">

                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0.6" >
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF87BEF5" Offset="0.2"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="AliceBlue" Offset="0.85"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF87BEF5" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                            <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

And I try to put the image in the button like this:

```
            <Button Name="btnZoom" Style="{StaticResource roundedButtonStyle}" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="btnZoom_Click">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="/Resources/lupa.png"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

In the visual editor of Visual Studio 2010 the image is showed, but when I run the application the image is not there.

And please, forgive my horrible english.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Build Action of the image is set to Resource (not Content or Embedded Resource)

Comment: Not problem. Please tick this answer as correct so other may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce it.

Try it in a test project, your context might be at fault here, try to narrow down the problem.